# Why the second nested for loop skip duplicated values during iteration?

Tags: python, loops

why the second for loop (j) skip `j=1` during the iteration if I input the list as `[3,3,4]`? I expect the answer_list is `[0,1]` after running.

Everything is fine if I input the list as `[1,2,4]`.

```
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums: object, target: object) -> object:   
        Answer_list = []
        for i in nums:

            print("i_index:", nums.index(i))
            for j in nums:
                print("j_index:" ,nums.index(j))
                if target - i - j == 0:
                    print (i,j)
                    Answer_list.append(nums.index(i))
                    Answer_list.append(nums.index(j))
                    print("Answer List:", Answer_list)

        return list(set(Answer_list))

s=Solution()
print(s.twoSum([3,3,4], 6))
```

Comment: Please don't post a useless `Solution` class. Always strive to give a [mcve]

Comment: What is your code expected to do?

Comment: `for j in nums` makes j take all values in nums. If nums is `[3,3,4]`, j is never going to be 1...

Comment: Also:  `index(3)` will never return 1 for `[3, 3, 4]`, but 0 in *both* cases. You should not  rely on `index` for your purposes. Use `enumerate` in your `for` loop.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `nums.index(j)` will return the index of the *first occurrence*. So it will not ever return 1 for `[3, 3, 4].index(3)`.

To get it working, iterate over `enumerate(nums)`, since that will also give you the index:

```
def twoSum(self, nums: object, target: object) -> object:
    Answer_list = []
    for i_index, i in enumerate(nums):
        print("i_index:", i_index)
        for j_index, j in enumerate(nums):
            print("j_index:" , j_index)
            if target - i - j == 0:
                print (i,j)
                Answer_list.append(i_index)
                Answer_list.append(j_index)
                print("Answer List:", Answer_list)
    return list(set(Answer_list))
```

You could also avoid some useless iterations by only having the inner loop search *ahead* in the list. Possibly like this:

```
        for j_index, j in enumerate(nums[i_index+1:]):
            print("j_index:" , j_index+i_index+1)
            if target - i - j == 0:
                print (i,j)
                Answer_list.append(i_index)
                Answer_list.append(j_index+i_index+1)
                print("Answer List:", Answer_list)
```